# Need help removing block of white space between footer widgets and footer

Tags: css, widgets, footer

This is the page in question:

https://k-12readinglist.com/category/reading-lists-for-elementary-school-children/

There's a large space between the footer widget areas (which are empty) and the footer. Setting the theme to no footer widgets doesn't resolve the issue.

Oddly, it only seems to occur on category pages.

I've tried using the chrome inspector and setting various classes not to display using CSS - but nothing seems to work.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with 
    the .block class assigned a css of min-height

```
.magazine .block {
   min-height: 480px;
}
```

Please change the min-height to auto or remove the 'block' class from that div element

Comment: Many thanks! That worked perfectly.